# Intersection of two lines tool

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-engine, cad

Is there any way to make intersection of two lines tool with extending lines option, so the result would be a point. the hardest part is when the lines have to be extended to intersect.

the tool will intersect int the cases described in the picture below.

this operation is a common CAD operation but i haven't found a tool or a snippet to do it in Arcobjects or Arcgis Engine 10.1.

Any help please.

[image]

Comment: An illustration of what you want would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the *ConstructIntersection* method on the 
[IConstructMultipoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000000vz000000) interface.  It constructs the points of intersection between two segments with options for extending the segments in order to locate additional points.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Extend Line tool?

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000004000000

> This tool extends line segments to the first intersecting feature
>   within a specified distance. If no intersecting feature is within the
>   specified distance, the line segment will not be extended. Tool use is
>   intended for quality control tasks such as cleaning up topology errors
>   in features that were digitized without having set proper snapping
>   environments.

Without a specified distance, lines will extend until an intersecting feature is found. A combination of that with Intersect seems like a possibility, especially because it allows extending to extensions as well as existing segments (both of which you illustrated above)

Comment: the extend tool is very good, but according to to my experience with it, sometimes it do not extend for no reason, sometime it is extended to the opposite direction of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

In Autocad Map 3d these are called drawing cleanup tools.
[image: cleanup]
esri will do these types of actions on topology.
You would need to create geodatabase topology of your feature class/classes and then show the topology toolbar.
Then you can display the topology errors, and see any violations of the "[must not have dangles" rule](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Geodatabase_topology_rules_and_topology_error_fixes/01mm0000000m000000/)
This topic applies to ArcGIS for Desktop Standard and ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced only.
If you don't like this route.
I would import the data into Map3d run the clean tools and export back to esri.

Comment: Excellent use of topology rules

Answer (score 1):

You want to create the "intersecting point" in an edit session manually (by clicking with your mouse - not as a batch task for all features)?

Then use the [Intersection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/at_the_intersection_of_two_segments/01m700000026000000/) tool from the Feature Construction toolbar:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i forgot to tell that i want to program the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

the [IRay.QueryFirstIntersection Method](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/QueryFirstIntersection_Method/002m0000032r000000/) seems to be the solution. the first line could be the Ray and second line could the argument to intersect.